# Problems with compiling Bibiliography with Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle, achemso

I am trying to use BibTex in order to produce a Bibliography section with "achemso" package.

My .bib file is inserted in the .tex file Folder, but Bibtex continues to give me this error:

"bibtex: Need exactly one file argument. Try `bibtex --help' for more information.
Process exited with error(s)"

My .bib file is automatically produced by Mendeley.

In the following lines I will put my code:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,openany]{report}
    \usepackage[top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm, bmargin=2.6cm, a4paper{geometry}
     \usepackage[default]{gfsbodoni}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{fbox}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=rosso, linktoc=page, citecolor = verde, urlcolor=blu]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{chemmacros}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{achemso}
    \definecolor{rosso}{RGB}{155, 0, 20} 
\definecolor{azzurro}{RGB}{51, 153, 255}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{0, 145, 0}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\linespread{1.3}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
\lhead{\scshape{Université de Padoue \\Programme de doctorat en sciences moléculaires}}
\rhead{A.A. 2022-2023}}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
\makeatother
    \begin{document}
   ....
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{riassunto tesi}
...
\end{document}
```

In advance I beg pardon for my english, which is not of the best.

Comment: the error is urelated to the contents of the file, it is your call of `bibtex` that is wrong, it should be (on the command line or editor setup) `bibtex myfile` but you have no argument (`bibtex`) or more than one argument (`bibtex aaa bbb`)

Comment: oh `\bibliography{riassunto tesi}`  try renaming the file not to have a space

Comment: I made what you suggested me and it worked perfectly! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\bibliography{riassunto tesi}`

implies you have a space in the file name using `"riassunto tesi"` might work but safest, most portable solution is to not have spaces in file names.

You or your editor is at some point doing

```
 bibtex some file with spaces
```

and `bibtex` is seeing that as multiple arguments.

```
 bibtex "some file with spaces"
```

should work but

```
 bibtex some-file-without-spaces
```

avoids the issue